# Как в gulp выполнить таски по очередно?

Tags: javascript, gulp

При первом запуске gulp, когда еще проект не собран, запускается browserSync, но все файлы еще не успели сгенерироваться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch'),
  plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
  prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  rimraf = require('rimraf'),
  browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  spritesmith  = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
  reload = browserSync.stream;

var path = {
 dist: {
  html: 'dist/',
  js: 'dist/js/',
  css: 'dist/css/',
  img: 'dist/img/',
  fonts: 'dist/fonts/'
 },
 app: {
  html: 'app/*.html',
  js: 'app/js/main.js',
  style: 'app/scss/main.scss',
  sprite: 'app/img/sprite/*.*',
  img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
  fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
 },
 watch: {
  html: 'app/**/*.html',
  js: 'app/js/**/*.js',
  style: 'app/scss/**/*.scss',
  img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
  sprite: 'app/img/sprite/*.*',
  fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
 },
 ignoreFile: {
  img: '!app/img/sprite/**'
 },
 export: {
  img: 'app/img/',
  style: 'app/scss/imports/'
 },
 spriteTemplate: 'sass.template.mustache',
 clean: './dist'
};

var config = {
 server: {
  baseDir: "./dist"
 },
 // tunnel: true,
 host: "178.150.110.97",
 notify: false,
 logPrefix: "Frontend_Devil"
};

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
 browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
 rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:dist', function () {
 gulp.src(path.app.html)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
 .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('js:dist', function () {
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('style:dist', function () {
 gulp.src(path.app.style) 
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(sass({
  sourceMap: true,
  errLogToConsole: true
 }))
 .pipe(prefixer())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
 .pipe(cssmin())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
 .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('image:dist', function () {
 gulp.src([path.ignoreFile.img, path.app.img])
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(imagemin({
  progressive: true,
  svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
  use: [pngquant()],
  interlaced: true
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.img))
 .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('sprite:dist', function () {
 var spriteData =
  gulp.src(path.app.sprite)
  .pipe(spritesmith({
   imgName: 'sprite.png',
   cssName: '_sprite.scss',
   cssFormat: 'scss',
   algorithm: 'binary-tree',
   cssTemplate: path.spriteTemplate,
   cssVarMap: function(sprite) {
    sprite.name = 's-' + sprite.name
   }
  }));
  spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.img));
  spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.style));
});

gulp.task('fonts:dist', function() {
 gulp.src(path.app.fonts)
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.fonts))
});

gulp.task('dist', [
 'html:dist',
 'js:dist',
 'sprite:dist',
 'style:dist',
 'fonts:dist',
 'image:dist'
 ]);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
 watch(path.watch.html, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('html:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.style, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('style:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.js, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('js:dist');
 });
 watch([path.ignoreFile.img, path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('image:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.sprite, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('sprite:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.fonts, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('fonts:dist');
 });
});

gulp.task('default', ['dist', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Я делал так с использованием gulpsync.sync:

```
gulp.task('watch', gulpsync.sync(['css:build', 'ionic_scss:build', 'dev_html:build']), function () {
    watch([path.watch.mustache], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('dev_html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.ionic, path.watch.ionic_theme], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('ionic_scss:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('css:build');
    });
});
```

Comment: добавил gulp-sync.
`gulp.task('default', gulpsync.sync(['dist', 'webserver', 'watch']));`
ссылка на изображение http://joxi.ru/KAxJJElc4nO3nm.

Comment: Скиньте с gulpsync.sync конфигурационный файл

Comment: какой еще конфигурационный файл?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный я имел в виду скрипт js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Devinora/kax6mj42/

Comment: По идее все верно. Судя по картинке joxi.ru/KAxJJElc4nO3nm таски запускаются последовательно. Минимизация файлов происходит вероятно из-за их изменения после запуска browserSync.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61209/discussion-between---and-glwhitefoot).

Comment: там запускается таск `image:dist` и в нем идет минификаци, но почему не ждет пока в этом таске все выполниться, а потом уже запускать browserSync.

Comment: Попробуйте как в чате написал.